# How could I fix this Bootstrap v5.0.2 Modal Problem? A Case Problem

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I just want to ask some assistance with this problem that I don't know why it is occurring. As the title imply, currently, I'm using the version 5.0.2 of bootstrap (js and css). The problem is that I can't make the modal functionality works despite trying to code all the required parameters. I don't know if I'm missing something or what but this error is taking me forever to solve. Thank you

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-5.0.2-css/bootstrap.css"> <!-- BOOTSTRAP CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    
    <script src="js/jquery-3.6.0.js" ></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js" integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-5.0.2-js/bootstrap.bundle.js"> </script> <!-- BOOTSTRAP JS -->
    <script src="js/script.js"> </script>
    <script src="js/scriptForEdit.js"> </script>



</head>
<body> 

    <!-- CONTENT -->

   ....
        
        <button id="previewFormattedSchedules" class="sp-btn-size lsc-btn-adjust btn btn-outline-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalcontainer">Preview Formatted Schedules</button>
        <button id="validateSchedules" class="sp-btn-size lsc-btn-adjust position-absolute btn btn-outline-primary">Validate</button>
        <button id="finalizeSchedules" class="sp-btn-size lsc-btn-adjust position-absolute btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalcontainer">Finalize</button>
                            



<!-- MODAL -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalcontainer" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modalcontainer" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title"></h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
     <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> 

    
</body>
</html>
```

Error:

```
modal.js:332 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined
    at Modal._isAnimated (modal.js:332)
    at Modal._initializeBackDrop (modal.js:205)
    at new Modal (modal.js:82)
    at Function.getOrCreateInstance (base-component.js:55)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (modal.js:434)
    at HTMLDocument.handler (event-handler.js:120)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like its the way you bringing in your scripts.

try starting only with this:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

For bootstrap inclusion. and also its good practice to have your scripts at the bottom of the html file,css can stay in the head.

here is a working codepen link:
https://codepen.io/munein/pen/abWVjQG

Comment: I added this to my code and now I'm *getting* this error.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 5 no longer requires jQuery. Refer to the [Bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/#js) to ensure you're using the correct scripts...

> "Place one of the following scripts near the end of your pages,
> right before the closing body tag, to enable them."

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Then the modal will work as expected: https://codeply.com/p/9NpwTOVDTi